# why is my container not in the center of the screen, even though I have changed the margins (left & right) to auto?

Tags: html, css

hey I am new to programming and I'm trying the css vertical text slide animator feature, when the feature runs smoothly the text turns out to be disproportionate (not in the middle of the screen) even though I've added margins (right & left) to auto

```css
@keyframes animate{
  0%,100%{
    top:0;
  }
  20%{
    top:0px;
  }  
  25%{
    top:-50px;
  }
  45%{
    top:-50px;
  }
  50%{
    top:-100px;
  }
  70%{
    top:-100px;
  }
  75%{
    top:-150px;
  }
  95%{
    top:-150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container " style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto">
      <h1 class="display-4 w3-center w3-animate-right" >Hi I'm Raffiel</h1>
      <div class="outer " style="display: block; position:relative;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 45px ;">I am, &nbsp;
        <div class="inner" style="position:absolute; border:0px solid #ddd; height:50px; line-height:50px; font-size:45px; text-transform:uppercase; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block; text-align: left;  font-weight: 400;">
          <span style="animation:animate 10s ease infinite; position:relative;color:#e58e26; text-align: left;">
            Graphic Designer<br>
            Digital Marketer<br>
            Video Editor<br>
            Web Designer<br>
          </span>
        </div>
          </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

strong text

Comment: you want to center the text right?

Comment: Yes, I want to make the text be in the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it should have been `position:relative` in order to take "space" and be included in the `text-align:center`. But you still need to fine tune this example.

```css
@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
  20% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  45% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  50% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  70% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  75% {
    top: -150px;
  }
  95% {
    top: -150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" style="text-align:center">
  <h1 class="display-4 w3-center w3-animate-right">Hi I'm Raffiel</h1>
  <div class="outer">
    <h1 style="font-size: 45px ;height:50px; line-height:50px ">I am,
      <div class="inner" style="position:relative; border:0px solid #ddd; height:45px; line-height 45px; font-size:45px; text-transform:uppercase; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block; text-align: left;  font-weight: 400; ">
        <span style="animation:animate 10s ease infinite; position:relative;color:#e58e26; ">
            Graphic Designer<br>
            Digital Marketer<br>
            Video Editor<br>
            Web Designer<br>
          </span>
      </div>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
@keyframes animate{
  0%,100%{
    top:0;
  }
  20%{
    top:0px;
  }  
  25%{
    top:-50px;
  }
  45%{
    top:-50px;
  }
  50%{
    top:-100px;
  }
  70%{
    top:-100px;
  }
  75%{
    top:-150px;
  }
  95%{
    top:-150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container " style=" width:100%; margin: auto;">
      <h1 class="display-4 w3-center w3-animate-right" style="text-align:center;" >Hi I'm Raffiel</h1>
      <div class="outer " style="display: block; text-align:center;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 45px;">I am,
        <div class="inner" style=" border:0px solid #ddd; height:50px; line-height:50px; font-size:45px; text-transform:uppercase; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block;  text-align:left; font-weight: 400;">
          <span style="animation:animate 10s ease infinite; position:relative;color:#e58e26; ">
            Graphic Designer<br>
            Digital Marketer<br>
            Video Editor<br>
            Web Designer<br>
          </span>
        </div>
          </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: still does'n changed bro, only the width is reduced.
the first line of text is centered but the second line (span) is not centered

Comment: can add any image description ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q__NgEpXGBGOzpHfWMfUaKKlvv1cJdHd/view?usp=sharing

sorry i don't know how to upload photos on stackoverflow, so i uploaded this via gdrive screenshot of my website. Thank you

Comment: its okay no issues check this out https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post  , I have edited answer!